# Delete a specific Launcher

Tags: launcher, delete

Excuse me Please:
In settling in to 14.04, I finally have my beloved GNOME back, and am currently trying to delete a launcher from the launcher bar(?) that is pointing to a Link that no longer exists.
Right-click it only gives Launch and Properties.
By what process can I delete this, or what folder is this "launcher bar" located at?
Thank you kindly for the assistance.
CAH

Comment: I don't have GNOME, but in Unity, you could just drag it into the trash for example. If not, all the `*.desktop` files should be in `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/` (`~` is your home directory). If you're sure the corresponding file is not usable any more, you can delete it, but I'd recommend you to move it to a different location first and check that you took the right one. It has no effect when it's outside those two directories. Note that the first one (`/usr/...`) is system-wide and needs root permissions to be modified. The second one is specific to your user.

Comment: thank you kindly for the response. I am unable to find anything specific in the first location, and the second location does not exist.

Comment: thank you kindly for the response. I am unable to find anything specific in the first location, and the second location does not exist. Using the Files ... Link(?) on the menu, I can access the hard drive, would the Links once dragged onto the Launcher be located some folder or maybe an ini or conf file? I gave the link a unique name, and did a search of the HDD, and found nothing,...

Comment: Sure that's your Shell is GNOME Shell? I don't have this entries in my right-click context menu. Please open your Launcher via `Super` key and create a sceenshot via `Shift-Print`

Comment: I did install gnome on/over(?) unitywill do. now that I see the winkey has been recruited for a different purpose, will

Answer (score 3):

The launcher in gnome, just like launcher in Unity, both have `gsettings` schema where the apps are listed. In this answer, I will be showing an example of deleting firefox from gnome launcher.

We find out what is the setting for `org.gnome.shell` schema and its key `favorite-apps`

```
xieerqi:$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps                                                                                                 
['empathy.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'shotwell.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'nautilus.desktop', 'yelp.desktop']
```

Next we copy the output and paste it into the command `gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-app`

```
xieerqi:$   gsettings set  org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['ubiquity-gtkui.desktop', 'evolution.desktop', 'empathy.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'shotwell.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'nautilus.desktop', 'yelp.desktop']"
```

As you can see, in the code above, I've removed `'firefox.desktop',` part. Also notice the double quotes at the end and the beginnign of the value

Bellow are the results before and after running the command:

[image]

[image]

Comment: excuse me, I received the following response when I typed in the command string "gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps" : **no such schema 'org.gnome.shell'**

Comment: @Ceyarrecks OK, so can you do this please: so choose one application from launcher that you have there pinned, and search for it  with `gsettings list-recursively | grep -i 'app-name' ` and copy and paste that to paste.ubuntu.com. Copy the link of your submission and link it in the comments here.

Comment: I launched Terminal, typed in the above command with the name of the launcher in question, and one that works, "k3b CD/DVD Burner" and neither resulted in anything.

Comment: Excuse me Please: can someone assist me in understanding why the above recommended command string resulted in NO results, no responses, no errors, nothing,....?

Comment: @Ceyarrecks I cannot quite explain that. `gsettings` is the standard , low-level tool to administer gnome shell. I don't understand why it's not working for you, even though we both have 14.04.  The only other suggestion I can give is to try it through `dconf`,another  tool.

Answer (score 0):

I edited and re-purposed the Launcher that refused to be removed by placing a url into the Location field "http://####.org/o/index.html" and it now launches the browser instead.
Thank you kindly for the assistance.
CAH